# How can I access View's state?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, view

I am trying to set theme's default **ENABLED_STATE** color for state disabled items in the list, so the list items won't look GRAY in my **ListView**. How can I get stateSet to use in the following code:

```
textview.setTextColor(textview.getTextColors().getColorForState(stateSet, android.R.attr.textColor);
```

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) I can see that ENABLED_STATE_SET is a protected field. So I can't  explicitly access it.

P.S. If any one know any other methods to change the disabled color of list item to theme's default color of enabled ( like using XML ) , please, write them

Comment: Have you tried using attributes? Check `?android:attr/textColorPrimary`

Comment: @K-ballo What the.. Yes, I have tried it many times, but it didn't work and gave me `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path)` error. But now it works. Why???

Comment: @K-ballo, okay, I tried android:textColor="?android:attr/textColor" and it failed. I also used "android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryNoDisable" and it worked, but when I clicked, it went black! instead of white  So, what's the difference?

Comment: I am not aware of `android:textColor` being a valid theme attribute, check https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using attributes? Check `?android:attr/textColorPrimary`.

Comment: Could you , please, point out why the text becomes black if I use `"?android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryNoDisable"`? thanks

Comment: @Godforever: Because enabled text would be black in your theme?

Comment: Asked a bit wrong, my text color black only when I click on the item using this attribute. It is white if I don't enable it. By default it becomes white when is enabled, and gray when disabled.